# Код русского символа

Tags: кодировка, java

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Java получить код **русской** буквы?
`int code = (int)('Б')` не проходит.

Comment: Что значит не проходит?

Comment: А у меня работает. И выводит 1041, что вполне ожидаемо.
Какая у Вас операционка? И может как то особо используете?

Answer (score 3):

```
    int code = (int)'Б';
    System.out.println(code);
    System.out.println("0x" + Integer.toHexString(code));
```

Выдаёт

```
1041
0x411
```

Что совершенно точно является правильным кодом буквы в юникоде.

Единственное, что может быть не так, это неверная кодировка исходного файла. Возможно компилятору передаётся неверная.